# Find a git commit in a repo history that was a directory rename or move

Tags: git

I'd like to find any commit in my repo which involved directory renaming.

I'm looking at [the Pro Git book on git-scm.com](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History) and

```
git log ...
```

looks like it will get me close but I can't see anything that will let me specify a directory rather than just a file, nor a move.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git` doesn't manage directories.  It only manages files.  There will be no record of a "directory rename"; you will just see a file rename for everything that was in the directory.

Consider the following example. I start with a repository containing a single directory `foo`:

```
git init .
mkdir foo
touch foo/file{1,2,3}
git commit -m 'initial commit'
```

Now I rename it:

```
git mv foo bar
git commit -m 'renamed foo -> bar'
```

Now `git show` shows me:

```
$ git show
commit 0429048856377cda39eb475248e142e1bfa4323b
Author: Lars Kellogg-Stedman <lars@example.com>
Date:   Mon Oct 30 08:52:24 2017 -0400

    renamed foo -> bar

diff --git a/foo/file1 b/bar/file1
similarity index 100%
rename from foo/file1
rename to bar/file1
diff --git a/foo/file2 b/bar/file2
similarity index 100%
rename from foo/file2
rename to bar/file2
diff --git a/foo/file3 b/bar/file3
similarity index 100%
rename from foo/file3
rename to bar/file3
```

You can get similar information using `git log --summary`:

```
$ git log --summary
commit 0429048856377cda39eb475248e142e1bfa4323b
Author: Lars Kellogg-Stedman <lars@redhat.com>
Date:   Mon Oct 30 08:52:24 2017 -0400

    renamed foo -> bar

 rename {foo => bar}/file1 (100%)
 rename {foo => bar}/file2 (100%)
 rename {foo => bar}/file3 (100%)
```

Comment: That gets me half way there. Is there a way to tell `git log` to output the 'rename' lines from the diff in the same way as `git show`?

Comment: Take a look at `git log --summary`, maybe?

Comment: Yes, I guess I can then grep on `rename ` or `=>` and I should be able to distinguish the directories from the files by eye.

Comment: Just as a side-note, git could be said to *manage directories* when you consider `git filter-branch --sub-directory-filter` which I'm working with at the moment. The parameter it takes as input is a directory. However the problem with this command is that it loses the history from files which have been moved.